# Excel How to organize repeating data

Tags: excel

I've got an massive excel (2010) file that is organised like this:

> - Column1  Column2
>
>   1. Name    John
>   2. Surname Doe
>   3. Address  smth1
>   4. ....
>   5. Name    Janet
>   6. Surname Smith
>   7. Address  smth2
>   8. ....
>   9. Etc

Now I want to convert it into normal tables with proper headers so it looks like this:

---

Name  Surname  Address .... 
John  Doe      smth1 
Janet Smith    smth2

PS It's my first time posting here. Hello everyone!

Comment: This site is not a script writing service. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your post and change it into a good question before it gets closed.

Comment: How many items of data do you have for each person? Is it the same amount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy all the data to another sheet in the workbook by putting the following formula into cell A1 in a new sheet and copying it across and down.

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,3*(ROW(A1)-1)+COLUMN(A1)-1,1)
```

I have made the assumption that your data is in Sheet1 and it starts at cell A1. Change Sheet1 for the actual name of the sheet and change $A$1 for the actual start of the data in the sheet (the $ signs are important).

I also assume there are 3 pieces of data for each person. If there are more, change the number 3 in the formula to the number of pieces of data.

Once you have used the formulas, if you want to make the changes permanent, copy the new data and paste as values. this will destroy the formula but leave you with the data intact.